# Increase MQTT Time between PUBLISH and PUBCOMP

Tags: mqtt, spring-integration-mqtt

I have configured a MQTT subscriber in spring using spring mqtt integration. In the handleMessage method I am doing certain business logic which takes time. While testing I noticed that when I am sending bulk number of messages the Broker republishes the same message as an original message (*I checked whether the Message payload is duplicate , it was sending as original*). **The MQTT Broker is publishing the message again even before the Subscriber can send PUCOMP**. QOS level is set to 2

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing long running tasks in the `handleMessage` callback as this is run on the MQTT Clients network thread.

If you have a long running task you should be handing it off to a separate thread pool to run.